# Showing a .png image in a window in wxPython

Tags: wxpython, png

How to show a `.png` image in a window in wxPython?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
png = wx.Image(imageFile, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png, (10, 5), (png.GetWidth(), png.GetHeight()))
```

Longer sample: http://web.archive.org/web/20090823114922/http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet337.html

Answer (score 7):

```
self.png = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, wx.Bitmap("path/image.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
```